# Spring - Return JSON from Map

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, rest

I'm trying to return a JSON representation of a Map as the return type of an action defined in my controller.

This is the method itself:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executeRetrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> executeAction() {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("message", "hello");

    return map;
}
```

But when I call that action, I keep getting an error 406:

```
HTTP Status 406 - description: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

That means the problem isn't related with Spring's conversion to JSON, right?

UPDATE - This is my context configuration:

```
public class ServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(ServletConfiguration.class);
    context.setServletContext(container);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}
```

}

Comment: Post your request headers. Your `produces` clause is awfully specific and usually not necessary (Spring does content negotiation for you). Also, how are you configuring your context--Spring Boot?

Comment: @chrylis I have updated my post. I've put the config there

Comment: If your method is producing json, then why return a map instead of a string? I believe most of the Java json libraries can turn Map objects into JsonObject, then toString that

Comment: @cricket_007 I had that implemented like as json.toString(). But when I tried to cosume it, it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? I'm not too familiar with Spring, but shouldn't there be some request parameters that you can access to get the POST data?

Comment: @cricket_007 Javascript couldn't realize that my json.toString() response body was in fact a json. Javascript wouldn't read it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Did what I should have done since the beginning. Spring can render an object into JSON for us. So, for a matter of consistency, organization and essential object oriented programming, I've created a model class containing all the attributes I needed as response and let Spring handle the rendering. Here is my final code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executeRetrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Student executeRetrieve(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    return loginService.executeRetrieve(user, password);
}
```

Thank you, everybody.